# IRC logging script

Tags: php, irc, logging

I am looking for a script to log chat from an IRC channel. If possible I would like the script to be able to output some nice HTML and allow the logs to be browsed by date.

A Google search has thrown up a couple of Perl and PHP scripts, but I am not sure they are entirely what I am looking for.

Comment: Just do a search for "irc bots" in Google - most of them have all those functionalities built in.

Comment: Most IRC clients already have logging capability. What you'd want is something to parse those logs - assuming yours doesn't have a "log to HTML" type capability.

Comment: @Marc B - I want to set up a server that logs files and makes them available through apache web server, so I am not sure installing a client would be the best option... it needs to be able to run as a background script.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest [Botzilla](https://github.com/bibby/botzilla). I've used it myself, and you can also run it as a background process via shell. It's also pretty easy to implement new classes to the bot which do some stuff with messages or react on special commands.

To run Botzilla as a background process later (after you've settled all the configurations and tested it successfully of course), you can use this little shell script to start it:

```
#!/bin/bash
nohup php5 -q botzilla.php > /dev/null &
```